# Hibernate and Ehcache statistics via JMX on production

Tags: performance, hibernate, caching, jmx, ehcache

I have a question more about opinions and experience rather then technical solution.

What do you think about turning on Hibernate statistics and Ehcache statistics via JMX console on production environment? Does it seem to be a good or horrible idea? And why?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that there are 2 salient issues here:

1. Are the statistics useful and can you access them in a useful way when published in JMX ?
2. Does the enablement of the statistics impact the overall performance of your system ?

We'll assume that #1 is true (otherwise why are we here ? :) )

As far as #2 is concerned, you would really have to test your application under load, both with and without the statistics, but my experience has been that both statstics components have negligible performance impact. Furthermore, regular collection and analysis of the these statistics may result in an improvement because it will/may help you find bottlenecks or parts of your system that are not using caches when they could be.

I suppose you could argue there are better ways of mining this information, like having a background thread periodically write stats to a log file, which works for simpler metrics like "How may elements are in cache", but many of the stats will not be available if the core engine does not have stats enabled  (like most of Hibernate's metrics). Plus, JMX has come a long away and there are all sorts of creative ways to access and analyze/report/visualize the data it exposes.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I did some benchmarking and it shouldn't affect my systems performance.

Answer (score 2):

The product I work on has it all - Hibernate stats, Ehcache stats, JMX and much more. But we expose Hibernate/Ehcache information via our special backend (rather than JMX) which is only accessible by admin users and use JMX for monitoring of various things that are bound to our SLA contracts. But if your product has no such backend, exposing db/cache stats via JMX doesn't sound like a wrong thing to me.

Turning on stats on a production environment is not a big deal. The cost is roughly one `AtomicLong` `incrementAndCount` operation per transaction which is virtually free. Unless you process millions of transactions per second, you should not notice any difference.